# JS Config Paths for Webpack '@' alias

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated the jsconfig file in my project so that all paths would resolve to src and this got intellisence working.

My config looks like this:

```
{
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "src/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

Now we've added Jest and are using the Webpack '@' alias, I've tried adding this as a path to the jsconfig file but can't get it to work. I tried:

```
{
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*", "src/*"],
      "@": ["src/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

What do I need to add to get '@' to resolve to the src directory? Would be cool to get IntelliSence working again.

Thanks